cron jobs are not getting triggered on aws ec2
I've sat a cron job, on root user and it does not wanna get triggered:
[root@ip-... tmp]$ crontab -l
0 19 * * * python3 /home/user1/lambdaCaller/call.py > /home/user1/lambdaCaller/error.log 2>&1 # error.log is always empty if ur wondering
* * * * * /usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime

[root@ip-... tmp]$ ls

[root@ip-... tmp]$ date
Mon Apr 15 15:40:58 UTC 2024
[root@ip-... tmp]$ date
Mon Apr 15 15:42:14 UTC 2024
[root@ip-... tmp]$ ls


i tried setting the cron on user1 user and ec2-user, but still nothing, i tried looking for cron logs in /var/log/syslog but the whole syslog folder isn't there in the first place.
how else can i verify that its running or what should i check?

Check status:

sudo service crond status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status crond.service ○ crond.service -
Command Scheduler
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
how can I active cron?

Steps to solve

The crond service on my device appears to be inactive (dead),
as indicated by the status output. To activate (start) the cron
service, you can use the following command:
 sudo systemctl start crond

which is responsible for running scheduled tasks defined in
cron jobs.
if you want to ensure that the crond service starts
automatically upon system boot, you can enable it using:
sudo systemctl enable crond

After running these commands, you can check the status again to
confirm that the crond service is active:
service as active (running).
sudo systemctl status crond 


